# Getting Started with Developing Desktop Themes

Tags: themes, development, desktop-environments

From a development standpoint, where would one start in developing their own themes for the Ubuntu Desktop.

Obviously, the artist would need image editing software like:

- [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), or
- [Photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/), via [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)

What other software would someone need that is Ubuntu Based?

Are there other concerns that one should look out for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Themes are based on CSS, which is the same language that's used to style web pages. So grab a CSS tutorial. You can do lots of stuff just using your favorite text editor. And as you mention, you'll probably want some tools to do some graphics.

You can read more about theming Gnome on their developer portal: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/theming.html